# tcpdf not showing html entities on pdf from html

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, fat-free-framework

I have a function on php that outputs pdf documents from html strings, the html might change and at times it contains entities like `&#10004;` for example. That should output a tick on the pdf but it currently does not, where am i going wrong?
Am using TCPDF version 6.2.13.
Here is my code for pdf generation

```
public function createPDF($html,$filename)
    {
        require_once(__DIR__ .'\tcpdf\tcpdf.php');

        $pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
        $pdf->lastPage();
        $f3 = \Base::instance();
        $dir=$f3->get('TEMP');
        $pdf->Output($dir .'/LV'.$filename.'.pdf', 'F');
        $web = \Web::instance();
        $file = $dir .'/LV'.$filename.'.pdf';
        $mime = $web->mime($file);         
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);        
        echo $f3->read($file);
    }
```

This function works fine for html that doesnt have entities or form inputboxes and checkboxes. 
Html entities are not shown, input boxes are not shown, where am i making the mistake?

Comment: I guess the font you're using doesn't support this character. Try another font. For example `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans');`

Comment: @xfra35, this worked for the html entity, but not for the input boxes, why can the input boxes be shown on the pdf, i dont think font affects them too?

Comment: @xfra35 i noticed when i set the font `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans');` not all html entities are shown, how do i know which entity is supported by which font?

Comment: To know which entity is supported, you can look at the font file inside the project [fonts/](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/tree/master/fonts) folder. For example, the default font file `helvetica.php` does only support character range 0-255 (see `$cw` variable), while the `dejavusans.php` does support a much higher range (including the #10004 character). But I guess it would be much easier for you to import your own font file (see [http://queirozf.com/entries/adding-a-custom-font-to-tcpdf](http://queirozf.com/entries/adding-a-custom-font-to-tcpdf)).

Comment: @xfra35, thanks about the html entities i think am sorted, but now the input boxes how do i go about that?

Comment: Well according to the [docs](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_writeHTML), not all HTML tags are supported, so it could be that checkbox inputs are not. You probably need to workaround it, either by adding the checkbox manually (using the [CheckBox()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_CheckBox) method), or by replacing checkboxes with Unicode special characters (which is maybe the reason why you were trying to print `&#10004;`).